# CSS framework including fonts

Tags: css, frameworks

I'm looking for a CSS framework including:

- Layout and grid (like the 960.gs framework) definitions
- A dropdown menu (or similar) definitions
- Fonts definitions
- Icons included (if possible)
- OpenSource
- Tested on the most common browsers (like Firefox, Chrome, IE, Safari, Opera,..)

I will create a administration system for my application written in JSF 2.0.

For now, I have template(s) which include a dropdown menu, and grid. But I would also like to have some icons and fonts. Thereby the question

Is there any "standard css frameworks" to use? Please, keep in mind that I'm more a backend programmer than a webguy, so the "reset css frameworks around" is not enough =)

Please help me, I'm totally lost in the css jungle =)

B.R

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure whether "Fonts" and "Icons" are wise criteria for choosing a framework. After all, they are trivial to add to any CSS framework, and other factors may be much more important. On the other hand, I can see the point of having a "one package" solution. Either way, do have a look at the top questions in http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=CSS+frameworks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend taking a look at [HTML 5 boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/), which you can use along with 960.gs

It's more like an HTML/css foundation for your site, and things like dropdown menus have to be implemented according to your needs, they're not something like grid systems, which are always the same in every site that uses them.
Just take a look at suckerfish and the likes - they can be added to your site easily enough.

Comment: Was just trying it out on Safari, and a lot of things in `demo/tests.html` act funny.  For example, in Hack 6, "Left align form legend to the inner text in IE 6,7", the outer borders of fieldgroups are removed with Boilerplate, but not without. So YMMV.

Comment: @Mike DeSimone that's the purpose of a reset, which boilerplate contains.

Comment: Thanks! I will check it out. Any more suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely recommend materialize css framework. I simplifies google's polymer design ideas.